# Is it possible to run electrum without QT on Ubuntu?

Tags: electrum

I want to run an electrum server and don't need the GUI. When I install it, I get:

```
ubuntu@comp:~$ electrum                                                                                      qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Could not connect to any X display.
```

Which is because I don't have an X display, obviously. How can I install with pure command line?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a server, you should run [ElectrumX](https://github.com/kyuupichan/electrumx). electrum-server is deprecated.